# Timediff of same field having same id

Tags: mysql

Supposed I have the fields as below:

```
id   fromstatus    time                   tostatus
1    ready         2016-08-05 08:36:27    break
1    break         2016-08-05 08:36:37    ready
1    ready         2016-08-05 08:40:27    break
1    break         2016-08-05 08:40:37    ready
```

How can I get the total time difference between the break status to ready status
Output should be

```
id   totalbreaktime
1    00:00:20
```

Comment: ...by redesigning your table...